# Deploying Shiny apps with local dataset

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to deploy my Shiny apps to xxx.shinyapps.io, but the problem is I use own dataset. I set my dataset to my directory, but when I try to deploy it I got error:

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:45220 Loading required package: DBIError in setwd("C:/Users/xxx/Dropbox/shiny/archive/db") : cannot change working directory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your dataset in a subdirectory of your shiny app directory (and change you code accordingly). Be sure to make the path to the data a relative path (not an absolute path - this generates a warning). This has worked well for me.

Comment: I put all of my db in directory "db" inside the application directory, and then I set `setwd("/db")` but I got error when try to deploy it `Error in setwd("/db") : cannot change working directory`

Comment: You need `"./db"` to indicate a relative directory (note the dot before the slash).

Comment: Thank you @JohnPaul! I had a mess of annotations (.rmd files) in my application directory before I knew how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

In server.R , have this code at the top

```
source("datarep.R)
```

Make a new .R file "datarep.R " in the same directory.
 That file has just one code

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways

1. Open a ".R"(navin.R e.g.) file in the app directory( where ui.r and server.R is placed) where you make the R object which contains the data
   (For example: dataS <- read.csv("XX.csv"); dataT <- read.csv("YY.csv"))

   and then in server.R , write the code initially: source(navin.R) 
   And use dataS, dataT objects as usual.
2. Place XX.csv and YY..csv in the same directory ( or any directory but then give the "relative path" )
   and do everything as usual

For example : I used local data to make shiny Apps
https://manaswink.shinyapps.io/TelecomTower/

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the comments provided by Paul

1. Insert the relative path to both `ui.R` and `server.R`
2. No need to pre-load the data file, it loads successfully along with `runApp()`
3. Finally, you can directly publish it to the `shinyapps.io`

Sample code:

```
For -> ui.R - where 'county.csv is local dataset'
county1<-read.csv("Data/county.csv")
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(..
..........
.......
```

Similarly,

```
For -> server.R
county1<-read.csv("Data/county.csv")
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {....
......
......
```